# find mean max and minimum in pandas and append the output in a single file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[image]    I want to find the mean maximum and minimum of columns of sample csv file with respect to 
    one particular column--- lets say if columns are a,b,c,d i want to find the mean , max, min 
    of column b,c,d w.r.t column a so that in result i can get the columns and the maximum , 
    minimum and mean of the columns w.rt a.
I am trying to do with the following code but i am not able to find the mean in the similar method as i have found min and max.
I am very much new to pandas.
Any help , how can i go about this problem

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

b=['fl_site_limit','eq_site_limit','fr_site_limit','hu_site_limit']

def get_df_attr():
  for i in range(len(b)):
    name = b[i]
    df1_max = df.groupby(['county'])[name].max()
    df2_max = df.loc[df[name].idxmax(), ['county', name]]
    df_max = df1_max.append(df2_max)
    #print(df_max)

    df1_min = df.groupby(['county'])[name].min()
    df2_min = df.loc[df[name].idxmin(), ['county', name]]
    df_min = df1_min.append(df2_min)
    print("====================")
    #print(df_min)
    print("==============")

    df1_mean = df.groupby(['county'])['fl_site_limit'].mean()
    print(type(df1_mean))
    df2=df['fl_site_limit'].mean()
    print(type(df2))
    df_mean=df2.merge(df1_mean.to_frame)
   # df2_mean = df.loc[df[name].idxmean(), ['county', name]]


return (df_max,df_min,df1_mean)

print(get_df_attr())
```

Comment: `df.groupby('a').agg(['mean','max','min'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang actually i am looking for only single mean value of complete column eg:- column a , column b , mean of column b

Comment: And that’s why you should always add a sample data and expected output.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have added the sample input and output